# Modal window text is not displayed when opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have mobile page, which is quite long. So when the button, placed in middle of page, is clicked, model page is displayed with content at the top of page. So this content of model page is not displayed after clicking this button on the page. I have to scroll up to see this content of mobile page ...

How to automate it: to go to top of modal page when  model page is displayed. This display is triggered by button which is in the middle of main page.

Hope this is clear:). jQuery probably should be helpful.

Comment: Can you post some code or show an example? What are you using to create the modal?

Comment: You need to show code.

Comment: I have some existing application, just for update. There is quite a lot of files, and sub files for review :)

Comment: Suppose the model window is opened, but it takes a few screens. How to move to the top of it, when it's opened?

Comment: Try `window.scrollTo(0, 0)`, basically scrolls to a particular point in the webpage specified by the two parameters. But please consider not imitating a scroll, its reduces UX value. Look into positioning the modal better.

Comment: window.scrollTo(0, 0) works:)... please create it as answer:). Thanks